# Can't access list using index

Tags: python, list

The following code shows that **IndexError: list index out of range**

Here i am trying to find a string which starts from "From" and then print the word next to it using .split()

```
if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "mbox-short.txt"
fh = open(fname)
count = 0
for a in fh:
    a=a.rstrip()
    b=a.split()
    if b[0]=="From":
        count=count+1
        print(b[1])
print("There were", count, "lines in the file with From as the first word")
```

for the following line
`if b[0]=="From":`

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: "Where am I going wrong?" Well, it says there is an `IndexError`, which is an `Error` that has to do with an `Index` you are using. It tells you specifically that the `index` you are using for the `list` is `out of range`. Your `list` is `b`, and your `index` is `0`. What must be true of `b` for that index to be out of range? Now, consider how `b` is produced. What must be true for the list to end up like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Validate the length before accessing the index of array.

`if len(b) > 0 and b[0] == 'From':`

Also make sure to close the file that is opened.

`fh.close()`

Answer (score 0):

well the problem is if a is empty `a.strip` will return nothing so you need to check for `if a != ""` and you should be good